# Can we use multiple Kafka producers in a multi-threaded environment in high traffic?

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka

We have a front layer which just receives messages and writes to the Kafka topics for back-end processing. We send the messages at a very high rate; per day we process 1 billion messages. We have a thread pool which accepts the messages and writes to the Kafka producer instance. Here I have created only one producer (single instance) which is shared among multiple threads.

Recently, I have been observing that 90% of the threads are in blocked state. I found out that Kafka is sending the data sequentially. There was a synchronized block in the `producer.send()` method in the Kafka Java driver:

```
def send(messages: KeyedMessage[K,V]*) {
    **lock synchronized {**
      if (hasShutdown.get)
        throw new ProducerClosedException
      recordStats(messages)
      sync match {
        case true => eventHandler.handle(messages)
        case false => asyncSend(messages)
      }
    }
}
```

The documentation says that we don't need to create multiple producer instances; one instance can be shared in a multi-threaded environment. But how can we do that? Or should we better create a pool of producer instances?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is recommended to share the publisher client across threads  is that it leads to better batching, as the messages are batched at partition level. Better batching leads to better compression (if enabled) and also better throughput. You can consider tuning parameters like buffer memory and linger.ms and batch size for optimizing the throughput. 
One this is done, then you can consider adding multiple producers.
Also, consider increasing the number of partitions for the topic, if the incoming rate for the topic is quite high.

Comment: I tried all the options you have mentioned but did not help for the high data rate i am dealing with. It became better once i increase the no of producer instances.

Comment: I have also encountered similar situation. It means you have fully optimized for the throughput that you can get from a single client. After this, adding more producer instances make sense.